# creating an array of buttons from a query - sizing with CSS

Tags: html, css, mysqli

Note I found the issue, I thought it was just not displaying the 2nd word, it is actually not in the CSS. I removed all CSS from the submit buttons and I am still just showing `robert`. $_post also just shows `robert`
If I

```
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
echo $row['name']."<br>";
}
```

It does show `robert tables` only when it loops through making the buttons does `tables` seem to get dropped from the name. If I change the  the name in the database to `robert_tables` the whole name displays OK.
I will repost this with a new question

---

My first endeavor into CSS and have come across a situation google hasn't revealed an answer for.

Starting with a query:`$query="select name from members where active=1 order by name";`

Next I am creating a table 5 columns wide that is 100% of the page, each column 20%

```
echo "<form action='individual.php' method='post'>";
$column = 0;
echo "<table class='fullheight' >";

   while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($column == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
        }
    echo "<td class='cellnopad'><input type='submit' class='submitbtn' name='name' value=".$row['name']." ></td>";

    $column++;
        if ($column >= 5) {echo "</tr>";
        $row++;
        $column=0;
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";



html{padding:0;
      height:100%;
      border:none;
      }

body {
    background-color: #93929F;
    background-image: url("shield1.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 10%;
    margin:0;
      padding:0;
      height:100%;
      border:none;
    }   

form {
    height: 90%;
    }

.fullheight{
    height:85%;
    width: 100%;
}

.cellnopad{
width: 20%;
padding:0px 0px;
}

/* copied this from an example and tweak*/
.submitbtn{
height:100%;
width: 100%;
opacity: 0.5;
cursor:pointer; /*forces the cursor to change to a hand when the button is hovered*/
padding:5px 0px; /*add some padding to the inside of the button*/
background:#35b128; /*the colour of the button*/
border:1px solid #33842a; /*required or the default border for the browser will appear*/
/*give the button curved corners, alter the size as required*/
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
/*give the button a drop shadow*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
/*style the text*/
color:#f3f3f3;
font-size:1.1em;
}
/***NOW STYLE THE BUTTON'S HOVER AND FOCUS STATES***/
.submitbtn:hover,.submitbtn:focus{
background-color :#399630; /*make the background a little darker*/
/*reduce the drop shadow size to give a pushed button effect*/
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
opacity: 1;
/*style the text*/
color:#ffff00;
font-size:1.2em;
}
```

I want to maintain 5 columns that stretch across the page I want it to change the number of "cells" based off of the results. and I want the buttons to be uniform. So far I have all of that, but the text within each button can exceed the button's dimension so it can chop off parts of names. Example, `robert tables` is only showing `robert`

I have been  unable to find an auto text size setting for a button , does one exist? if so what is it, and how would it be used? 
Also any help in doing this better woudl be appreciated, but keep in mind I am just starting, so baby steps please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kypros was able to answer the question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26613918/only-first-word-populating-the-value-field-on-a-submit-button)

`value=".$row['name']."`   needs to be `value='".$row['name']."'`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly change the structure as below.

```
1. #cellnopad to .cellnopad
2. #submitbtn to .submitbtn
3. <td id='cellnopad'> to <td class='cellnopad'>
4. <input type='submit' id='submitbtn' name='name' value=".$row['name']."  to <input type='submit' class='submitbtn' name='name' value=".$row['name']." />
   You also need to close <input> tag.   
5. .submitbtn {
       height: 40px; // instead of height: 100%;
   }
```

Make sure you use ID for elements which are not getting repeated. It must be only one per page.

Read : http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Comment: Nice catch on the input tag. I will read up on the link you posted. I have been reading up a lot on css the past few days and thought that # was the way to go

Comment: Unfortunately, no it did not. It appears to be more in how `echo "<td class='cellnopad'><input type='submit' class='submitbtn' name='name' value=".$row['name']." ></td>";` is reading the `row$['name']` when there is a space in the name field.

Comment: you can use trim() fucntion to remove extra spaces from $row['name'].