# Only first word populating the value field on a submit button

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am doing a query and populating buttons with the results:

```
$query="select  name from members where active=1 order by name";
```

If I do a  simple:

```
while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row['name']."<br>;
}
```

I get a list:

> Mary123
>
> JOE
>
> Robert Tables

However if I :

```
<table>
$column = 0;
   while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($column == 0) {
        echo "<tr>";
        }
    echo "<td class='cellnopad'><input type='submit' class='submitbtn' name='name' value=".$row['name']."> </td>";
    $column++;
        if ($column >= 5) {echo "</tr>";
        $row++;
        $column=0;
        }
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

My buttons look like

> Mary123
>
> JOE
>
> Robert

As you can see the name `Tables` gets dropped from the name and only the value of `Robert` is shown.

I initially thought the name wasn't being displayed due to the size of the text versus button size, but I have proved that is not the case by removing the `CSS` and checking the `$_POST` value on `individuals.php`. Also,if I change the name in the database to `Robert_Tables` it works fine.

Is there something I am doing wrong? What do I need to change to get the value to show both words and the space?

Comment: what is this? `$row++;` it's an array.

Comment: @lolka_bolka Remnant, thanks for noticing. Since i was trying to specify columns, I  inadvertently went down the path of counting rows. I quickly abandoned that, but forgot to pull it from the copy of the code I used for the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem relies on the fact that you forgot to quote the `value` parameter of the input with quotes `''`. See here you have:

```
 value=".$row['name'].">
```

when it should instead be:

```
 value='".$row['name']."'>
```

And that is breaking your generated `html` markup, see simple snippet below on how the output is handled when you omit the quotes:

```html
<input type='submit' class='submitbtn' name='name' value=asd asd>
<input type='submit' class='submitbtn' name='name' value="asd asd">
```

Comment: That code snippet did the trick, I can see clearly now. I assumed that `'name'` was making it all inclusive for the value parameter. Also, thanks for saying I `forgot`, it makes me sound like I know what I am doing ;)